# Using f for both frequency and function

Tags: symbols

How can I differentiate the the letter f between function and frequency if using ν is not an option here and I'm strictly limited to f to represent frequency?

Comment: Why are you forced to use "f" for the function?

Comment: You might use `\varphi` (for ‘phunction’…). Or use an upright f (`\mathrm{f}`) for the frequency.

Comment: while in theory possible, an upright frequency would be against norms for equation formatting and depending on the field this is either absolutely fine or a capital crime. Just so you know you might have to pay attention on what is typeset upright and what isn't.

Comment: Definitely change the symbol for the function, use g, h, s, x, y, whatever, but don't use two slightly different f's because it can be too confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are fonts where the lowercase "f" is slightly in the text font than in the math font. At the moment, the only example I can think of is Cochineal, for which a math font can be accessed with `newtxmath`. Using this, you could have two distinct lowercase italic "f" symbols that would still match the font used in the document.

Here's an example with Cochineal.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage[cochineal]{newtxmath}
\newcommand*{\freq}{\mathord{\mathit{f}}}
\begin{document}
Let \(f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\), and let \(\freq\) denote the frequency.
\end{document}
```

However, even if these two "f" symbols are distinct, this is still confusing. I must say that if I were in your situation, I would just use another symbol for the function or for the frequency.

Comment: I suggest using `\colon` (`amsmath`) instead of `:` for function definition.

Answer (score 1):

I add my proposal using `mathastext` and taking `f` from fouriernc font. You can use the $f$ both the frequency and for the functions.

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
    \usepackage[basic,default mathsizes]{mathastext}
    
    % Taking f from fouriernc font
      \DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}
      \DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
      \DeclareSymbolFont{fourierletters}{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
      \SetSymbolFont{fourierletters}{bold}{FML}{fncmi}{b}{it}
      \DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`f}
    \makeatletter
      \DeclareMathSymbol{\mst@f}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`f}
    \makeatother
\begin{document}
$f$ it is the frequency or the classic-usual $\nu$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to have the classic `f` of computern modern (CM) if you use `$\mathit{f}$`.